# Ruby on Rails - jrails not site wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototype

Is it possible to configure jrails so that it only replaces the ruby on rails helper methods for some parts of the site?

I am currently in a project where we are doing a staggered migration to jQuery so the site wide choice is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you'll have to dive deep into jrails code and make some major edits in it's code.